# Excel formula for the generation of a pattern

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below value, in A1. When i drag down this should increment in such a way as shown below. B should increment first, keeping C constant. Once B reaches maximum value, which is 2, then C should increment. The maximum value for C actually depends on the row number, rownumber divided by 2 or rownumber divided by 2 rounded to next integer.

[image]

We are trying to use excel fucctionalities to generate such a series of pattern for the some use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
="A:B[" & MOD(ROW(A1)+1,2)+1 & "]:C[" & ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/2,0) & "]:D"
```

If you have a lot of these, you can save some calculations by having two slightly different formulas in the first two rows, and then you can copy and paste both of them together over many rows:

```
="A:B[1]:C[" & ROW(A2)/2 & "]:D"
="A:B[2]:C[" & ROW(A2)/2 & "]:D"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a condition so that depending on the row where the cell (any cell) is, it should use one value or other, or one function or another.

Use can use another cell, outside the table, to set the values you want to keep constant, so you could change them at anytime, and use a reference to the from the cells where you have the conditions.

To keep some values constant, use the '$' before them.